# Post to Web Service using Javascript (from C#)

Tags: javascript, c#, cordova

Good day everyone,
I am facing a slight problem.

Up until last week our mobile application connected to an in-house Web Api, which in turn connected to web services run and maintained by our partners.
Problem is, we would like the remove our Web Api as the middle man, and connect directly from our Cordova app (Javascript) to the Restful service.

Below is the C# code I am trying to emulate, any and all help would be appreciated:
(At this point I'm sure everything is right, except the authentication but I might be wrong)

QUESTION:
How can I achieve this in Javascript (If it is at all possible)

```
public static AuthenticateResult CheckLogin(LoginModel login)
        {
            var serviceClient = new WebClient();
            var proxy = serviceClient.Proxy;
            proxy.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username_goes_here", "password_goes_here");
            serviceClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";

            try
            {
                var requestHeader = new UnauthenticatedRequestHeader
                {
                    Code = ConstantModel.PartnerCode,
                    Partner = ConstantModel.PartnerName
                };

                var authenticateRequest = new AuthenticateRequest
                {
                    Username = login.Username,
                    Password = login.Password,
                    Handset = "iPhone Emulator"
                };

                var serviceRequest = new
                {
                    header = requestHeader,
                    request = authenticateRequest
                };

                var jsonizedServiceRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(serviceRequest);
                var requestBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonizedServiceRequest);
                var requestStream = new MemoryStream(requestBytes);

                var ms = requestStream.ToArray();

                var responseBytes = serviceClient.UploadData("Url_goes_here", "POST", ms);
                var jsonizedServiceResponse = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(responseBytes);
                var authResult = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthenticateResponse>(jsonizedServiceResponse);

                return authResult.AuthenticateResult;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return null;
            }
        }
```

What I have so far in Javascript is (this returns a Bad Request error):

```
btnTestClick: function () {
                    var header = {
                        Code: 'guid_goes_here',
                        Partner: 'partnerid_goes_here'
                    };
                    var request = {
                        Username: 'username_goes_here',
                        Password: 'password_goes_here',
                        Handset: 'iPhone Emulator'
                    };
                    var myrequest = {
                        header: header,
                        request: request
                    };

                    var string = JSON.stringify(myrequest);
                    var data = tobytearray(string);

                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "url_goes_here",
                        crossDomain: true,
                        data: data,
                        contentType: 'application/octet-stream;',
                        dataType: "json",
                        username: 'auth_username_goes_here',
                        password: 'auth_password_goes_here',
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            debugger;
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            alert("error");
                        },
                        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
                        },
                    });

                    function tobytearray(str) {
                        var bytes = [];
                        for (var i = 0; i < str.length; ++i) {
                            bytes.push(str.charCodeAt(i));
                        }
                        return bytes;
                    }
                }
```

Comment: ...and what exacly is wrong?

Comment: I specified above that I am looking to emulate this C# code in Javascript

Comment: what is your output/response?

Comment: In the on error function, I receive the following:
readyState: 4,
status: 400,
errorMessage: Bad Request

Answer (score 0):

What I see from your examples is the difference in the dataType used in the 2 examples. 
In the C# example you use `serviceClient.Headers["Content-type"] = "application/json";` and in the javascript implementation you use `contentType: 'application/octet-stream;'`.
octet-stream should be used for attachments and not JSON objects.

The webservice could be validating the request on the content-Type and if the test result is that your request is invalid it can return (and should return) a `HTTP 400 - Bad Request`.

I don't know the webservice where you shoot your requests at and what validations it does but try changing that contenttype in the javascript implementation to `contentType: 'application/json;'`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply, I have tried sending content type JSON to the same effect, I also receive a Bad Request error.

I was thinking it might be something to do with the authentication, as I have read multiple articles stating that from Javascript to WebServices one can only use basic authentication.

Was hoping someone might have some more experience on this

Comment: I don't really have experience with this, only with token based authentication or direct membership provider authentication. Isn't it possible for you to contact your suppliers or the ones you try to authenticate to? It looks like the two messages are the same from your example. Could you get the message sent from both systems? You could use [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) for this.